# Wildcard cert marked invalid when not specifying FQDN, even though it's in search domain?

Tags: ssl, https, dns

I have a valid wildcard ssl cert for our (internal) domain - *.stmn.company.local

I have a site that I want to use with this cert, let's say - https://server.stmn.company.local

In firefox/chrome, if I navigate to that FQDN url, it works fine, I do not get an invalid cert warning or security warning.

However, if I navigate to "server/" or "https://server/" or "http://server/" (the trailing slash is necessary to tell firefox/chrome that this is an internal site and to go directly to it, without searching) I get an error in firefox that my certificate is not valid.

> server uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for *.stmn.company.local (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

This is unexpected to me because my search domain is configured with stmn.company.local so in theory any dns name I don't fully qualify should have that appended onto it?

```
bryce-e@channel:~$cat /etc/resolv.conf
search stmn.company.local company.local
nameserver 10.99.42.30
nameserver 10.99.42.31
```

Am I misunderstanding how search domain works, or SSL certs?

Answer (score 0):

The domain name that is typed in the browser must match. You need to make your site accessible at the same url internally and externally, or modify your certificates to include all the names that will be used.

If routing is problematic, use of 'split' dns might be helpful. With that you can have a domain name resolve to a different ip address internally vs externally.

It isn't sufficient to just have the name resolve to the right ip.

Comment: There is no 'external' way to access the site, it only exists inside our LAN.

There should be no difference between typing 'server' and 'server.stmn.company.local'

Comment: @PartyTime: The browser does not see that the OS actually tries a longer name instead of the given to get the IP address. Thus the browser has only the name from the URL and this must match with the certificate. Thus there is a difference between giving a hostname and the FQDN in the URL from the view of the browser. Result of DNS lookup do not matter for certificate validation, only names matter.

Comment: I believe the comment above by @SteffenUllrich is the correct answer, but not sure what the SO policy on marking a comment as an answer is....